# Why is Utility Network Analyst toolbar grayed out?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, utility-network-analyst

When I pull up my Utility Network Analyst toolbar I cannot use it because its grayed out. My method for pulling it up is Customize > Toolbars > Utility Network Analyst. I am not able to use any of the features of this toolbar.

Why is my Utility Network Analyst toolbar grayed out?

Comment: Do you have the checkbox for Customize > Extensions > Utility Network Analyst Checked?

(If it even exists. I've never used that extension)

Comment: be sure your licensed that extension in ArcGIS Administrator

Comment: I'm having the same problem with 10.5 and wondered if it was a versioning issue. I saved a copy for an earlier version (10.3) and opened it with the earlier 10.3 in the VCL at my school and still have the same issue.